# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and weighted data

Tags: r

I want to perform a ks.test to compare two distributions. I was thinking in using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but the problem is both distributions have to be weighted. Any idea of how to do it?

Here are my data:

```
  library(tidyverse) 

my_data_2018 <- tibble(Var = c(900, 1500, 350, 1200, 750, 100,125,250),
                      my_weights_2018 = c(2.2, 3.1, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3, 6.8, 12, 25))

my_data_2019 <- tibble(Var = c(32, 21, 21, 900, 1500, 350, 1200, 750, 100,125,250,300),
                       my_weights_2019 = c(2.2, 3.1, 8.2, 2.2, 3.1, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3, 6.8, 12, 25, 1))
```

I found this code to create a new ks_weighted function but I am not sure how make it work with my example data

```
ks_weighted <- function(vector_1,vector_2,weights_1,weights_2){
    F_vec_1 <- ewcdf(vector_1, weights = weights_1, normalise=FALSE)
    F_vec_2 <- ewcdf(vector_2, weights = weights_2, normalise=FALSE)
    xw <- c(vector_1,vector_2) 
    d <- max(abs(F_vec_1(xw) - F_vec_2(xw)))

    ## P-VALUE with NORMAL SAMPLE 
    # n_vector_1 <- length(vector_1)                                                           
    # n_vector_2<- length(vector_2)        
    # n <- n_vector_1 * n_vector_2/(n_vector_1 + n_vector_2)

    # P-VALUE EFFECTIVE SAMPLE SIZE as suggested by Monahan
    n_vector_1 <- sum(weights_1)^2/sum(weights_1^2)
    n_vector_2 <- sum(weights_2)^2/sum(weights_2^2)
    n <- n_vector_1 * n_vector_2/(n_vector_1 + n_vector_2)


    pkstwo <- function(x, tol = 1e-06) {
                if (is.numeric(x)) 
                    x <- as.double(x)
                else stop("argument 'x' must be numeric")
                p <- rep(0, length(x))
                p[is.na(x)] <- NA
                IND <- which(!is.na(x) & (x > 0))
                if (length(IND)) 
                    p[IND] <- .Call(stats:::C_pKS2, p = x[IND], tol)
                p
            }

    pval <- 1 - pkstwo(sqrt(n) * d)

    out <- c(KS_Stat=d, P_value=pval)
    return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ks` function from FastDR to obtain Weighted Kolmogorov-Smirnov Statistic and then calculate the p-value for a two-sided test.

FastDR was written by Greg Ridgeway, who is a professor at UPenn. I think the method will be reliable.

First, get the package from GitHub.

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)
install_github("gregridgeway/survey","patch-1")
install_github("gbm-developers/gbm3")
install_github("gregridgeway/fastDR")
```

To calculate the KS test stats, based on your data, you can use the following code:

```
library(fastDR)

Var         <- c(my_data_2018$Var,my_data_2019$Var)
weights     <- c(my_data_2018$my_weights_2018,my_data_2019$my_weights_2019)
treat       <- c(rep(0,nrow(my_data_2018)),rep(1,nrow(my_data_2019)))

ks.test.stats <- ks(x=Var,z=treat,w=weights)
```

You will get the following KS test statistic:

```
## KS Test Statistics
ks.test.stats
[1] 0.1660517
```

Lastly, to calculate the p-value for a two-sided test, you can use this following codes:

```
### "Two-Sided" P-Value for KS Tests Statistics from R

p.value <- 1-.Call(stats:::C_pSmirnov2x,
                   STAT=ks.test.stats,
                   length(my_data_2018$Var),
                   length(my_data_2019$Var))
p.value

> ks.test.stats
[1] 0.1660517
```

NOTE: **If you have a problem with downloading the package, try to change your R version. It appears that the dependency of the FastDR is not working well with R version 4.00. I used R version 3.63 to carry out this calculation.**