# weighted kolmogorov-smirnov-test for single variable

Tags: r, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov, goodness-of-fit

Kolmogorov–Smirnov test KS can be done for the single variable as

```
x <- rnorm(50)
ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
```

Results:

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.057841, p-value = 0.9927
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

How can I compute the weighted KS for single variable as well? I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks!

```
library(Ecume)
ks_test(x, y,thresh = .001)
```

I wanted to reproduce the test results of modified KS test of this paper on Jarque –Bera Test and its Competitors for Testing Normality – A Power
Comparison.

[Jarque –Bera Test and its Competitors
for Testing Normality – A Power
Comparison](https://www.scinapse.io/papers/2142225982#fullText)

Comment: Did you search before posting? And do you realize that a "one-sample KS test is really just a 2-sample KS test against a specified theoretical distribution, typically one with similar first and second moments?  So ...  Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513941/kolmogorov-smirnov-test-and-weighted-data

Comment: @IRTFM Yes, I did! It didn't work. I couldn't install that fastDR package

Comment: @IRTFM I got this error: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace

Comment: So is there a reason not to update `cli`? I initially got an error about an old versy of pkg: `survey` but running install.packages"survey") proceeded without error and then installing `fastDR` from github went smoothly.

Comment: @IRTFM Here is the error message:  byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 3.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'sessioninfo'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jishan/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/sessioninfo'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sessioninfo’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: I’m not an R parser. So I can only see inside that message that your current version of the cli package is OUT-OF-DATE.   WHY NOT UPDATE IT?

Comment: I tried with that, but still not working!

Comment: WHAT did you try? The tail end of that message said something about an attempted installation of a “sessioninfo” package. There is a “sessionInfo” function but it’s not a package name. Spelling is critical in R.

Comment: It worked, but i just found that fastDR test is for multivariable whereas i wanna test the normality of residuals which is just single variable.

Comment: I wanted to reproduce the test results of modified KS test of this paper. https://www.scinapse.io/papers/2142225982#fullText

Comment: Generally procedures for multivariable tasks will have the same results when used with a model that has only one predictor as are produced by single variable tests.